# Login is not happening and failure redirect is calling again and again

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

Login is not occurring instead the failure redirect is calling repeatedly.
The password and username already exist so that may not be the issue.

Router file

```
 router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {

    passport.authenticate('local',{
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/user/register_login',
        failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password.'
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

passport.js file

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var alert= require('alert');
module.exports = function (passport) {

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (email, password, done) {

        User.findOne({email: email}, function (err, user) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
                alert(err);

            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false);
                alert('No user found!');
                  console.log(message);
            }

           bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, isMatch) {
               if (err)
                    console.log(err);

                if (isMatch) {
                    return done(null, user);
                      console.log("ohk");
                }
                else {
                    return done(null, false);
                    console.log(message);
                    alert('Incorrect Password');
                }
        });
      });
    }));

    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: ```// passport middleware
require('./config/passport')(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

Comment: I have attached app.js

Comment: Can you see if you are getting a user back from `User.findOne`? You can check by adding `console.log(user)` before the if blocks in callback. Also its worth noting that code after `return` statements will not be executed such as in the `isMatch` if blocks.

Comment: Are you getting log for `console.log("ohk");`? Any checks done on "/", redirecting it to `failureRedirect`? 

Try enabling preserve log in chrome browser console if your log message is clearing after each redirect

Comment: No I am not getting "ohk" in console.log() . Yes the failureRedirect is working well and redirecting to right url. Checked it with different URLs too.

Comment: Do I have to pass post form details  in the route('/login') or passport takes it all.